# Wordpress function to convert from GIF to JPG and set it as the POST THUMBNAIL/FEATURE IMAGE

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image

So i have a WordPress site with a bunch of animated GIFs and i manage to convert my images from GIF to JPG using this PHP script:

```
<?php

//This function gif2jpeg take three parameter as argument. two argument are optional
//first will take the gif file name. second for file name to save the converted file. third argument is an color array

//EXAMPLE:
$gifName = $_GET['gif_name']; //ABSOLUTE PATH OF THE IMAGE (according to its location)
$c['red']=255;
$c['green']=0;
$c['blue']=0;
echo gif2jpeg($gifName, '', $c);


function gif2jpeg($p_fl, $p_new_fl='', $bgcolor=false){
  list($wd, $ht, $tp, $at)=getimagesize($p_fl);
  $img_src=imagecreatefromgif($p_fl);
  $img_dst=imagecreatetruecolor($wd,$ht);
  $clr['red']=255;
  $clr['green']=255;
  $clr['blue']=255;
  if(is_array($bgcolor)) $clr=$bgcolor;
  $kek=imagecolorallocate($img_dst,
                  $clr['red'],$clr['green'],$clr['blue']);
  imagefill($img_dst,0,0,$kek);
  imagecopyresampled($img_dst, $img_src, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, $wd, $ht, $wd, $ht);
  $draw=true;
  if(strlen($p_new_fl)>0){
    if($hnd=fopen($p_new_fl,'w')){
      $draw=false;
      fclose($hnd);
    }
  }
  if(true==$draw){
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($img_dst);
  }else imagejpeg($img_dst, $p_new_fl);
  imagedestroy($img_dst);
  imagedestroy($img_src);
}

?>
```

HOW TO USE?

```
Add the above code into a php file 'convertGifToJpeg.php'
Add an <img tag. <img src="http://mydomain.com/convertGifToJpeg.php?gif_name=/images/animated_image.gif" width="200" height="200" />
```

and its working like a charm!

Now I'm building a function to get an static image (JPG) from a GIF ( ANIMATED IMAGE ) and set it as the POST THUMBNAIL/FEATURE IMAGE every time a GIF is uploaded to a POST by doing this:

```
function gif_to_jpg($post_id) {
// if attachment is a gif extension
if($attachments[$i]['mime'] == 'image/gif' ){
$gifurl = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_id ); // GET THE URL OF THE MEDIA IMAGE UPLOADED
// build the string
$gif_to_jpg = 'http://mydomain.com/convertGifToJpeg.php?gif_name=' . $gifurl . '';
  // next, download the URL of the JPG image
        media_sideload_image($gif_to_jpg, $post_id, 'Sample GIF TO JPG image.');

// find the most recent attachment for the given post
        $attachments = get_posts(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_parent' => $post_id
            )
        );
        $attachment = $attachments[0];

        // and set it as the post thumbnail
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment->ID );} // end if
} // gif_to_jpg
add_action('save_post', 'gif_to_jpg');
```

But its not working at all... Can you guys help me out?

Comment: I'm not exactly certain what you're expecting to have take place in `media_sideload_image` but it's definitely not going to convert a gif to a jpg by passing the image into that function.

Comment: I'm not an expert... every help will be appreciated!

Comment: You have the trouble in the beggining of your code.

Where do you set `$i`? And as I can see wp_get_attachment_url get $attachment_id as first parameter. I talking about these 2 lines: 

    `if($attachments[$i]['mime'] == 'image/gif' ){
    $gifurl = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_id );`

Comment: i remove the $i and change wp_get_attachment_url( $post_id ); to wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); and nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a class for this called [GifExtractor](https://github.com/Sybio/GifFrameExtractor)

This will extract frames from a gif file and allow you to do what you'd like with the resources (save them with **imagejpeg** or png with **imagepng**).

Looking at your code though, you have no definition of **$i** so it's essentially grabbing nothing from your post input and doing not able to really process anything here.

I would use **wp_check_filetype()** in this case.. It will return the extension and mime of your media in an array you define of your serverside gif file

```
$getMimeType = wp_check_filetype(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
var_dump($getMimeType);
```

var_dumping this data (if the image exists) should return an array with ['ext'] and ['mime'] containing the data needed for this portion.

For converting a gif to JPG we would first grab the frames (singular or multiple):

```
function extractJPGFromGif( $imagePath ) {

        $frameImages = null;

        if ( \GifFrameExtractor\GifFrameExtractor::isAnimatedGif( $imagePath ) ) { // check this is an animated GIF

            $gfe = new \GifFrameExtractor\GifFrameExtractor();
            $gfe->extract( $imagePath );

            $frameImages = $gfe->getFrameImages();

        }

        return $frameImages;
    }
```

This will simply return the frames. A very simplistic function as well that can be easily expanded on with dimensions, etc.

We then grab the 1st frame and convert the resource inside our save_post hook:

**Note:** You can make sure your directory is even writable to begin with is_writable($directory_path) before you begin working with files / directories on the server side.

```
function wpse_20343192_ryan( $post_id ) {
        /**
         * Get extension of media to see if it is a gif file
         */
        $fileExtension = wp_check_filetype( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) );
        if ( $fileExtension['ext'] == 'gif' ) {

            /**
             * Get server location of gif image file
             */
            $gifurl = get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) );

            /**
             * Extract frames from gif file
             */
            $gifFrames = extractJPGFromGif( $gifurl );

            /**
             * Takes 1st gif frame, converts it to the existing gif file and then sets output quality to 75
             * It then sets the post thumbnail if conversion was successful
             * Note: You can create multiple frames - i suggest looking into the GifExtractor codebase in github
             */
            if ( @imagejpeg( $gifFrames[0], $gifurl, 75 ) ) {

                /**
                 * Generate our arguments for new media attachment
                 */
                $jpgInsert = array(
                    'guid'           => $gifurl,
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpg',
                    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $gifurl ) ),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                );

                /**
                 * Insert new media attachment and contain new attachment ID into $thumbnail_id
                 */
                $thumbnail_id = wp_insert_attachment($jpgInsert, $post_id);

                /**
                 * Set post thumbnail with new converted thumbnail
                 */
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $thumbnail_id );
            }
        }
    }
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_20343192_ryan' );
```

GifExtractor class allows many more possibilities such as getting durations of gifs, specifying time period of gif and what frames to get , etc ... I highly suggest looking into the code base on Github and familiarize yourself with the possibilities.

You can also build out your own custom jpg file location for when you do a imagejpg conversion.

**Note:** Keep in mind you will need to include the class libraries into your wordpress environment or utilize a composer environment and grab them from [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sybio/gif-frame-extractor)