# Validate file type using javascript on IE

Tags: javascript, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible to read the type of file selected in an input field when on browsers (like IE8) that don't support javaScript FileReader?

I want to detect if the selected file is an image or not.  I will have server side validation, but would also like the user to know if the file is correct before submitting.  I've tried a number of different solutions but can't find any support for IE8...

This javascript doesn't work in IE8:

```
<input id="uploadImage" type="file"name="myPhoto" onchange="isImage();" />

var upload_image = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
function isImage() {
    if (
        upload_image.files[0].type == 'image/jpg' ||
        upload_image.files[0].type == 'image/jpeg' ||
        upload_image.files[0].type == 'image/png' ||
        upload_image.files[0].type == 'image/gif' ||
        upload_image.files[0].type == 'image/bmp'
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

This method doesn't help either:

```
function isImage(a){
    return a.indexOf(".png") != -1 && a.type == file;
}
```

The 'accept' parameter also does not work in older IE versions:

```
<input name="img1" id="img1" type="file" accept="image" />
```

Comment: You really need to inspect the files on the server anyway, so for incapable clients you can just allow anything and relay any server-generated errors.

Comment: For IE or browser that don't support FileReader you could use a fallback to check the file extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation of file extension before uploading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file)

Comment: You can certainly check the file extension, but there's no reason for somebody crafting an exploit to follow file naming rules. The server really needs to inspect the file contents.

Comment: I had a suspicion it couldn't be done, or at least not easily.