# How to validate .mp4, .mp3 and PDF file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

According to select option I need to upload pdf or mp3/mp4.

If I select book or question paper, I need the validation to  only to upload pdf or doc file,

If I select audio,  I should upload mp3 only.
If I select video,  I should upload mp4 only.

Please help me to do this validation using javascript. I need just condition . the rest will be done through backend

```
<select id="upload_material" onchange="val()">
      <option>Select Material Type</option>
      <option value="1">Question Paper</option>
      <option value="2">Book</option>
      <option value="3">Audio/Video</option>
</select>
<label class="myLabel">
     <%= f.file_field :attachment, :onchange => "get_extension($this.value)" %>
     <!--  <input type="file" style="margin-left:80px;" name="filetwo"> -->
     <span>Browse</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Provide the Javascript code that you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation of file extension before uploading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file)

Comment: Client side validation is insecure, use server side validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [javascript-test-function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) to test the filename and / or filetype, if it contains your desired filetypes.

Something like:

```
types = /(\.|\/)(mp3|mp4)$/i;
//file is the file, that the user wants to upload
file = data.files[0];

if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)) {
    alert("file is valid");
else{
    alert("file is invalid");
}
```