# File type validation on file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, c#-4.0, file-upload

I have written below lines of code

```
<section class="col col-md-6">
  <label for="file" class="input input-file">
    Upload Image/Video
    <label for="file" class="input input-file">
      <div class="button">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadSlider1" runat="server" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value" />Browse</div>
      <input type="text" readonly />
    </label>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUploadSlider1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="UploadSlider1" OnServerValidate="ValidateFileSize1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UploadSlider1regularexpression" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UploadSlider1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Only Images are allowed" SetFocusOnError="true" CssClass="state-error" ValidationExpression="^.*\.((j|J)(p|P)(e|E)?(g|G)|(g|G)(i|I)(f|F)|(p|P)(n|N)(g|G))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</section>
<section class="col col-md-6">
  <label for="file" class="input input-file">
    Upload Image/Video
    <label for="file" class="input input-file">
      <div class="button">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadSlider1" runat="server" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value" />Browse</div>
      <input type="text" readonly />
    </label>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUploadSlider1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="UploadSlider1" OnServerValidate="ValidateFileSize1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UploadSlider1regularexpression" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UploadSlider1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Only Images are allowed" SetFocusOnError="true" CssClass="state-error" ValidationExpression="^.*\.((j|J)(p|P)(e|E)?(g|G)|(g|G)(i|I)(f|F)|(p|P)(n|N)(g|G))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</section>
```

Now I want that user should be allowed to upload image and video files only. Please help me how to do validation for both types in one regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation expression should be like this

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.png|.PNG|.jpg|.JPG|.gif|.mp4|.mpg|.3gp)$
```

Add as many variation as you need with `|` as separator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.png|.PNG|.jpg|.gif|.mp4|.mpg|.3gp)$" ControlToValidate="UploadSlider1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please select a valid Image or Video File file." ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" />
```

**JavaScript version:**
If you feel easy with JavaScript you can follow this SO post [validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237161/5104101)