# Accept csv files only via a Html file input

Tags: javascript, html

Html file input tag is given below which only accept .csv files.

`<input id="csvFileInput" type="file" accept=".csv"/>`

That works perfect. But my case is..

In the file chooser window, user can select 'all types' instead of '.csv file'.
Then user can choose any file type.
How could I handle that situation?

Can I handle that changing only Html tag? or another Javascript tactic to be implement?

Thanks,
Best Regards..

Comment: You really need to validate that they've uploaded a valid file **server-side**, rather than client-side. What back-end technology are you using?

Comment: After selecting the file, you have to validate the file extension. This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file

Comment: @Obsidian Age I'm using php as backend. But I need to validate on client side.

Comment: Thanks Aravinder..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a validation `onchange` an validation the file extension.

Though in html the input type accepts `.png` but in js the regex is failing since it is designed to accepts only csv. You can modify the html to accept only csv

```js
var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(csv)$");

function triggerValidation(el) {
  if (!(regex.test(el.value.toLowerCase()))) {
    el.value = '';
    alert('Please select correct file format');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="csvFileInput" type="file" accept=".png" onchange='triggerValidation(this)'>
```

Answer (score 2):

## HTML will always allow user to click 'All files'

Whether you restrict the "accept=" using the extension or the mime type or both, the user can always switch to 'All files'.

#### Javascript is needed

For example,

```
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('csvFileInput');
selectedFile.onchange = function(e){
    switch ((this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/i)[1]).toLowerCase()) {
        case 'csv':
        case 'txt': /* since they might have a CSV saved as TXT */
             /* ... insert action for valid file extension */
        default:
            /* Here notify user that this file extension is not suitable */
            this.value=''; /* ... and erase the file */
    }
};
```

#### Server side validation is also needed

Remember the user can always defeat the process by renaming (for example) an .exe to a .csv, so where relevant you should also check the content of the file to meet your criteria, on the server side.

Comment: just a side note switch case always increase code complexity , object mapping is a better approach

Comment: Thanks Eureka..Server side validation is a overwork I think..I managed it by only a simple JS validation.