# FCkeditor image upload allow extentions on asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor

[image]

This upload option are allowing all type of file like that jpg,png,docx,exe. But i would allow permission only jpg,png file type in javascript.Also i display a 
alert message when user submit send it to server button.I have a server check for this type of image validation.But i would give a javascript validation.     Thanks in advance

Comment: You can start by adding `accept=".png,.jpg"` to the FileUpload. A user will then only see those type of files. He/she can then still select "all files" and select another type, but this will help 95% of the users select the right file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation of file extension before uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file)

Comment: I have faced this problem in FCkeditor. So your solution is applicable for normal jabascript image upload problem.