# Is it possible to start executing PHP script on a multipart/form-data file upload request before file is uploaded?

Tags: php, file-upload

It should be be a common use-case, but I can't find whether it's achievable at all.

I want to validate a multipart/form-data uploaded file extension on server-side - must I wait for the file to fully upload?
I might be missing something, but it doesn't make sense, especially when handling large files.

Can't I execute PHP **before** file is uploaded, get metadata and maybe cancel the request altogether?
I know I can split to two separate requests, I'm looking for a single-request solution, if applicable

Comment: Generally speaking, no. Your PHP script in most (actually all AFAIK) implementations gets invoked _after_ the server and/or PHP process has handled the data. Instead, if you really want to validate the extension you'll need to use [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237161/231316). However, the file input type also supports the [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#attr-accept) so I'd encourage you to enforce it there if possibly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait until the file is fully uploaded so you can then validate. There is no one single-request solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an Apache/Nginx HTTP server, it executes PHP scripts only after it finished loading the whole request from the client - which is too late for your use case, as Sergio in the other answer correctly points out.

---

There is a single-request solution in PHP, but you need to **have control over the HTTP requests in your PHP script**.

You can chose to not use Apache, but instead start a HTTP server from your **php-cli** (either by using the native [socket](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) functions or some HTTP server package such as [react/socket](https://packagist.org/packages/react/socket) that uses them in the background).

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:8080', $loop);
$socket->on('connection', function (React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $connection) {
    // here you can have $connection->on(...) event handlers
});
$loop->run();
```

Then you can have handlers that handle each chunk of the incoming request (example from the react/socket package, specifically [ReadableResourceStream](https://github.com/reactphp/stream#readableresourcestream)):

```
$connection->on('data', function ($chunk) {
    echo $chunk;
});
```

And instead of echoing the chunk, you can validate its contents and call `$connection->close()` if you need, which effectively terminates the unfinished upload.

But this whole thing is a complex solution, and I'd recommend to use it only for a upload service that is **completely separated** from the application that generates the form page (which can still run under a regular Apache HTTP server because it's just much easier).

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it before interact with the server in the frontend, in PHP the script executes when request is finished