# How to validate file/image file type ,size and exist before submitting form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm adding a lengthy form into the database which contains several files and images. In order to avoid having an error after submitting where I might lose all the typed data, can I validate the file before submitting the form? I would like to check the allowed extensions, file size and existing file. Is it possible with jquery/Ajax? I couldn't find a better example on the internet.

This is what I have done for my other page (Just to get the idea of what I'm looking for):

```
        if(isset($_POST['pass_addbtn']))
    {
        $emp=$_POST['emp_add_name'];
        $pass_no=$_POST['pass_no'];
        $arrival=$_POST['arrival'];
        $pass_expiry=$_POST['pass_expiry'];
        $pass_status=$_POST['pass_status'];
        
    
        $file=$_FILES['passport_copy'];

        $doc_name=$_FILES['passport_copy']['name'];
        $doc_tmpName=$_FILES['passport_copy']['tmp_name'];
        $doc_size=$_FILES['passport_copy']['size'];
        $doc_error=$_FILES['passport_copy']['error'];
        $doc_type=$_FILES['passport_copy']['type'];

        $docExt=explode('.', $doc_name);
        $docActualExt= strtolower(end($docExt));

        //files allows to upload

        $doc_allow=array('pdf','png','jpeg', 'jpg');
        
    
            if($doc_error === 0)
            {
                    if(in_array($docActualExt, $doc_allow))
                    {
                    if(!file_exists("empPass_upload/".$doc_name)) 
                    {  

                        if($doc_size < 10000000)
                        {

    

                        //  $docNewName= uniqid('',true).".".$docActualExt;
                            $docDestination='empPass_upload/'.$doc_name;
                            move_uploaded_file($doc_tmpName, $docDestination);

                            $query="INSERT INTO passport (pass_no,e_id,arrival,pass_expiry,pass_status,pass_copy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                            $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                                if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query)){
                                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sissss",$pass_no,$emp,$arrival,$pass_expiry,$pass_status,$doc_name);
                                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                
                                    $_SESSION['success']="New Passport Added";
                                header('Location: employee.php');

                                }
                                else{
                                    $_SESSION['status']="Not added";
                                    header('Location: employee.php');

                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $_SESSION['status']="The file is too big!";
                            header('Location: employee.php');                    
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['status']="Existing file";
                            header('Location: employee.php');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['status']="Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                    header('Location: employee.php');
                
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['status']="Sorry,error updating file.";
                header('Location: employee.php');
            
            }

        }
```

Comment: Ideally validation is done twice: the first time in the UI to ensure people have provided the minimum amount of data *and* that data is within expected bounds, then again by the back end to ensure anything missed by the front end (or provided via some other means) meets expectations. You can accomplish what you seek with JQuery or plain JavaScript 

Comment: _“I couldn't find a better example on the internet”_ - “javascript file upload validation” typed into Google leads you to explanations how to check the file suffix in no time (f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4234589/1427878), and if you also add “size”, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3717793/1427878 etc. are found quickly as well.